# Excel VBA and ADO - Error 3704 Operation is not allowed when object is closed

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

Im attempting to add data stored on an excel spreadsheet to an access database. But, before each row is added, i want to check if that row of data is already present in the database, and if so, skip the row and move to the next one.Trying to avoid duplication of data..

From a completely blank database, my code enters the first two rows of data and then throws up the error.

> Error 3704 Operation is not allowed when object is closed

When I stop and then run the code again, the next two rows of data are entered and the error pops up again! and so on...

Im very new to ADO and can't figure out what the issue is, so all assistance is appreciated.

Here is the full block of code:

```vb
Function GetDb() As ADODB.Connection
    Set GetDb = New ADODB.Connection
    GetDb.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA Source=" & GetPath & ";"
End Function
```

```vb
Function GetPath() As String
    GetPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\db.accdb"
End Function
```

```vb
Sub AddToDBSTACKFB()
  'searchfirst try

  Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim adoComm As New ADODB.Command
  Dim adoRS As Recordset

  Dim RecordRow As Long, Lastrow As Long
  Dim OrderID As String, Site As String, ProductName As String
  Dim ShipTo As String, ShipVia As String, Quantity As Long, Email As String

  Set adoConn = GetDb

  Lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  With adoComm
    Set .ActiveConnection = adoConn

    .CommandText = "select [OrderID],[Site],[Product Name],[Ship To],[Ship Via],[Quantity],[Email] " & _
                   "FROM DATA " & _
                   "where [OrderID] =? and [Site] = ? and [Product Name] = ? and [Ship To] = ? and [Ship Via] = ? and [Quantity] = ? and [Email]= ?"

    .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Name:="OrderID", Type:=adVarChar, Size:=255)
    .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Name:="Site", Type:=adVarChar, Size:=255)
    .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Name:="Product Name", Type:=adVarChar, Size:=255)
    .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Name:="Ship To", Type:=adVarChar, Size:=255)
    .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Name:="Ship via", Type:=adVarChar, Size:=255)
    .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Name:="Quantity", Type:=adDouble)
    .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Name:="Email", Type:=adVarChar, Size:=255)


    'Loop through all the records on the sheet one row at a time
    For RecordRow = 2 To Lastrow
      OrderID = Sheet1.Cells(RecordRow, 1).Value
      Site = Sheet1.Cells(RecordRow, 2).Value
      ProductName = Sheet1.Cells(RecordRow, 3).Value
      ShipTo = Sheet1.Cells(RecordRow, 4).Value
      ShipVia = Sheet1.Cells(RecordRow, 5).Value
      Quantity = Sheet1.Cells(RecordRow, 6).Value
      Email = Sheet1.Cells(RecordRow, 7).Value

      .Parameters(0).Value = OrderID
      .Parameters(1).Value = Site
      .Parameters(2).Value = ProductName
      .Parameters(3).Value = ShipTo
      .Parameters(4).Value = ShipVia
      .Parameters(5).Value = Quantity
      .Parameters(6).Value = Email

      'First, check if the record is already in the database
      'if its not, then enter that row of data into the database
      Set adoRS = adoComm.Execute

      If (adoRS.EOF And adoRS.BOF) Then '<< ERROR ON THIS LINE EACH TIME
        adoComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DATA([OrderID],[Site],[Product Name],[Ship To],[Ship Via],[Quantity],[Email]) " & _
                           "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        adoComm.Execute
        Set adoRS = Nothing
      Else
        Set adoRS = Nothing
      End If

    Next RecordRow

  End With

  adoConn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You change the recordset's underlying command object while the recordset is opened. Use another command object to insert data.

Comment: Unrelated to why your code doesn't work, but... As a database guy I have to speak up. If you're trying to stop data duplication, it's better to have a unique constraint on your table.

Comment: thanks for the replies guys. ckuhn203, the database has an autoincrementing primary key in addition to the above fields. The duplication would be data on the excel sheet itself. Several people update it, so what i dont want is the same row of data being entered twice. Gserg, i will give that a go :). ie creating another command object, assigning it its own commandtext etc. is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is right. The important part though is to assign the same connection for ActiveConnection.

Comment: Primary keys are unique constraints aren't the same thing. Although, a primary key IS a unique constraint. Do yourself a favor and look into adding one on your table.